# Keyboard delay in wine while playing games

Tags: 22.04, wine, games

Hi i just installed a game using wine but there is keyboard delay, for example if i press W for like 3-4 seconds it remains pressed in the game for 6-7 seconds and while it's pressed other keys don't work